# Azure Active Directory B2C log in user with specified email address

Tags: c#, uwp, openid, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using the following code to sign in the user at first time with AAD B2C using Microsoft IDP.

```
var localAccounts = (List<IAccount>) await AADB2C.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();

var authResult = await AADB2C.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(AADB2C.ApiScopes)
    //.WithAccount(GetAccountByPolicy(localAccounts, AADB2C.PolicySignUpSignIn))
    //.WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .WithLoginHint(WindowsUser.Email)
    //.WithExtraQueryParameters("login_hint=" + WindowsUser.Email)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

I try to achieve to specify the login email address, so when the user log in the email address should be filled out at least. (Or make it readonly would be even better). For this I use the .WithLoginHint extension but it doesn't work.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

AAD B2C will be sent the `login_hint` param in the authorization request based off your code. Use a network trace in Chrome browser to confirm. Since there is only one IDP configured, AAD B2C redirects the user to Microsoft Account login.

AAD B2C will not pass through the `login_hint` parameter to the federated IdP when using the Built In user Flows, hence your observation of it "not working".

If you build this using Custom Policies, following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account-custom?tabs=applications) and add the following to your MS Account OIDC `ClaimsProvider`, B2C will pass through the `login_hint` using a [claims resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview).

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
```

You also need to define the [claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema) `prompt` as follows:

```xml
      <ClaimType Id="prompt">
        <DisplayName>oidc prompt param</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText/>
      </ClaimType>
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check it.